# Xpages version of @IsAgentEnabled?

Tags: function, xpages

I currently upgrading an Notes app to Xpages. The app uses @IsAgentEnabled to hide/show sets of buttons to enable/disable the agent.

What is the XPage way of doing this if @IsAgentEnabled is not available ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can set visible property using this peace of code

```
database.getAgent("agentname").isEnabled()
```